# KendoUI Grid custom groupable object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to make a grid `groupable` on columns field but the columns are object.

```
{
  Gestionnaire : 
     { id: 4, nom:'nomgestionnaire'},
     {..},
      ..
}
```

I have success for `sortable`:

```
columns: [
     field: "Gestionnaire"
     title: "Gestionnaire"
     sortable:                  
         compare: (a,b) =>
               @compareColumnFields(a.Gestionnaire.Nom, b.Gestionnaire.Nom)
]
```

with `@compareColumnFields` function is :

```
if a is b
    return 0
else if a > b
    return 1
else
    return -1
```

and for `groupable`?

```
groupable : ...
```

Comment: no solution to this problem you have to go with something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those in the same situation as me , I completely change solution. Instead of making me a function that returns true and false , it giving it the object in full, I just give the string .
For my example I give directly `a.Gestionnaire.Nom` and `b.Gestionnaire.Nom`, and **THEN** you can call :

```
groupable: true
```

In fact it was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wanting to allow the user to actively group columns.

In that case, all you need is:

`groupable: true`

in the main structure of the grid.

For example:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({ 
    columns: [
        {
            fields: "Guestionaire",
            title: "Guestionaire",
            sortable:
                compare: (a,b) =>
                    @compareColumnFields(a.Guestionaire.Nom, b.Guestionaire.Nom)
         }, 
         {...placeholder for other columns...}
    ],
    groupable: true
});
```

Kendo has a sample of this at http://dojo.telerik.com/ejehe
Ignore the SelectRow and Expand/Collapse stuff and that ought to be the same as what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: groupable:true doen't work with column field object. Gestionnaire is an object !

Comment: I see. Could you add your kendoGrid initializing method to your post so I can see what the whole thing looks like and I can test some things out on dojo.kendo?